# React native: Can't generate APK

Tags: android, react-native, apk

Hey I'm trying to generate an APK for android for my app, and I'm following the instructions on the React Native website.

When I get to the following step I get an error.

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/Alia/Desktop/GroceriesApp/android/build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GroceriesApp'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_8iveiv727pjojj7ekhwcamif9$_run_closure2@30c4e352] on root project 'GroceriesApp' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.582 secs
```

I don't know why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share /GroceriesApp/android/build.gradle file?

Comment: I think you've modified the wrong build.gradle, android blocks can only exist inside android/app/build.gradle and not android/build.gradle. This may be useful for you https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html